# isDaylightSavingTime returns NO although my time zone does observe DST

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, timezone, nstimezone

Checking `-[NSTimeZone isDaylightSavingTime]` is giving me `NO`, and I don't know why. On my system I have the correct time displayed, and my time zone is Eastern US -- New York, which observes DST.

```
NSTimeZone *sZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
BOOL isDST = [sZone isDaylightSavingTime];
if (isDST) 
    NSLog(@"\n Daylight saving");
else
    NSLog(@"\n Not in Daylight saving");    // This prints
```

Can anyone please explain why this would be happening, and a possible remedy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440058/how-do-you-return-the-system-time-zone-as-a-string

Comment: That is not your real code. Please paste in your real code.

Comment: Why do you expect `isDayLightSavingTime` to return `YES` today?

Comment: Yes, I realized that after Matt answered it.. may be I was thinking too much earlier, however I gained info that isDaylightSavingTime is date-based on current date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`isDaylightSavingTime` is date-based; the answer depends on the current date. Today is January 6, and on January 6 in your time zone, daylight saving time is not in use. Thus, the result you are seeing is correct.

Comment: My bad !! seriously.  How could I forget ?  Thanks for the answer !

Comment: You are probably just _wishing_ there was more daylight. :)